# Rewriting MySQL date functions for SQLite

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

Please help me rewrite this query from MySQL to SQLite format:

```sql
SELECT MAX(pubdate) as pubdate, 
COUNT(DISTINCT post_id) AS count, 
DATE_FORMAT(pubdate,"%b-%y") as month 
FROM posts 
WHERE pubdate >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 5 MONTH) 
GROUP BY month 
ORDER BY pubdate ASC
```

Basically, I want to get the count of all posts for the last 5 months grouped by the month, but I have difficulties rewriting `DATE_FORMAT(...)` and `DATE_SUB(...)` functions.

`pubdate` has the standard MySQL `TIMESTAMP` format (`2011-06-21 20:05:01`)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```sql
SELECT MAX(pubdate) as pubdate, 
COUNT(DISTINCT post_id) AS count, 
strftime('%m-%Y',pubdate) as month
FROM posts 
WHERE pubdate >= datetime('now','-5 month')
GROUP BY month 
ORDER BY pubdate ASC
```

Is the closest that I can make it clean-looking. However, this will return '01-1999' format for `month`. If you want it to be 'Jan 99' you'll have to have some form of messy case statement.

I don't have access to sqlite at the moment, so this code has not been tested.

Comment: Hey Sam, thanks for the reply. I tried your query, but the strange thing is that it returns **all** the months and not the _last_ 5 months. I tried to change the `-5 month` to `-5 months` but it still returns _all_ the months. Of course, I needed the last 5 months since current date so changing the `WHERE` part to `WHERE pubdate >= datetime('now' , '-5 months')` correctly returns the last 5 months. But now that you mentioned it, I'm thinking, why `datetime(pubdate,'-5 months')` has no effect?

Comment: @Tony That was my fail, hah. I suppose a WHERE (Date > Date - 5 months) is going to allow everything. /fail

Comment: Sam: but `WHERE pubdate >= datetime('now', '-5 months')` works in this case because my last post is from yesterday, but what if my last post is from 2 months ago, how do i modify the `WHERE` part to return all months from last 5 months since the date of last post?

Comment: @Tony I changed it to max(pubdate) instead of 'now'. I think that should fix it.

Comment: Sam: unfortunately, it doesn't work, you get `SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 misuse of aggregate: max()`. Just to be clear, you answered my question (`WHERE pubdate >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 5 MONTH) ` translates to `WHERE pubdate >= datetime('now' , '-5 months')`), I'm just curious what if my last post is very old and i want to get all months from last 5 months since the date of last post.

Comment: Try switching the WHERE to a HAVING after the GROUP BY ?

Comment: `HAVING pubdate >= datetime(max(pubdate),'-5 month')` again return all months.

Comment: Hmm. I'm not able to figure out any different approach here, sorry.

Comment: Thanks for answering the original question though, as for the second question, I noticed something like `WHERE ( date(pubdate) > date('2010-01-01') AND date(pubdate) < date('2010-05-01') )` works. So I guess i'm up to some subquery foo or such. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 7):

Here is the [Date And Time Functions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) of SQLite.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the docs. It helped me understand a couple of important points.